# Drawing a Sudoku grid and labelling its “elements”

Tags: sudoku

What would be my best bet at the following image in LaTeX?

[image: Sudoku]

Would I have to use something like TikZ? I'm very inexperienced at it, so I'd prefer if I didn't have to use a package as immense (for me) as TikZ.

I have not found a way to label the elements (block, band, stack) using any of the Sudoku packages that are present on CTAN.

Comment: you don't need any packages for that just \begin{picture} and a few \line

Comment: http://www.ctan.org/ctan-portal/search/?phrase=sudoku

Comment: @Sigur: That was the first thing I did, but I did not find a way to label the elements (block, band, stack) using any of these packages.

Comment: @d125q, since you said *inexperienced* I decided to suggest you. You can edit your post and inform that.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I will try what you suggested and see if I get any results soon. If I do, I'll report back.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\setlength\unitlength{1cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}

\begin{picture}(9,9)

\linethickness{3pt}

\multiput(0,0)(0,3){4}{\line(1,0){9}}
\multiput(0,0)(3,0){4}{\line(0,1){9}}


\thinlines

\multiput(0,1)(0,1){2}{\line(1,0){9}}
\multiput(0,7)(0,1){2}{\line(1,0){9}}

\multiput(3,4)(0,1){2}{\line(1,0){6}}

\multiput(4,0)(1,0){6}{\line(0,1){9}}

\multiput(1,0)(1,0){2}{\line(0,1){3}}
\multiput(1,6)(1,0){2}{\line(0,1){3}}

\put(1.5,4.5){\makebox(0,0){block}}

\put(-.7,4.5){\makebox(0,0){band $\left\{\rule{0pt}{1.5cm}\right.$}}

\put(1.5,9.5){\makebox(0,0){stack}}
\put(1.5,9.2){\makebox(0,0){$\overbrace{\hspace{3cm}}$}}

\end{picture}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

<sub>Can't let `picture` mode alone in `tikz` jungle! ;)</sub>

Using `tikz`

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\tikzset{mydeco/.style = {decorate,decoration={brace,raise=5pt, amplitude=1.0ex,}, thick}
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x in {1,2,4,5,7,8}{
     \draw[thin,line cap=round](\x,0) -- (\x,9);
     \draw[thin,line cap=round] (0,\x) -- (9,\x);
     }
     \foreach \x in {0,3,6,9}{
     \draw[line width=2pt,line cap=round](\x,0) -- (\x,9);
     \draw[line width=2pt,line cap=round] (0,\x) -- (9,\x);
     }
     \draw[mydeco] (0,3) -- node[left=10pt]{Band}(0,6);
     \draw[mydeco] (0,9) -- node[above=10pt]{Stack}(3,9);
     \node[fill=white,minimum width=3cm-2pt,minimum height=3cm-2pt] at (1.5,4.5){Block};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]